# Manage customer newsletter user-roles issue

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, newsletter, ce-1.9.2.4, acl

Clean install of Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

I created a user
and created a custom role for this user by going to the roles section.

When I've selected the option of "all" in roles it works perfectly. I can go to:

```
Customers > Manage customers > Select customer > Newletter
```

and activate the newsletter on this page.

But when I use custom roles, as in, I select "custom" but still select each and every option that's there ( Which to my knowledge, is the same as "all" that has been proven to work, like I mentioned before ) I don't have the same outcome. I can navigate to the exact same section as before, select the checkbox and save and it even gives me the according success message

"The customer has been saved." but the checkbox reverts to it's previous state.

I've looked, but couldn't find a ACL issue like I mention above.

Is this a known issue, and have I not looked good enough. Or is there a bypass that I can use for this to make it possible for not correct ACL roles to still perform this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code in [Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::saveAction()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php#L310), it checks for the ACL resource `customer/newsletter` and silently does not save the subscription if you are not allowed to.

Now here's the problem: Neither `Mage_Newsletter` nor `Mage_Customer` define this resource, so it's not possible to give a restricted user access to it. **You found a bug.**

As a workaround you can create your own module that defines the missing resource. It only needs a minimal `config.xml` and module activation file and this `adminhtml.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <customer>
                        <children>
                            <newsletter translate="title">
                                <title>Newsletter</title>
                                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                            </newsletter>
                        </children>
                    </customer>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Then you will be able to add the *Customer > Newsletter* permissions to your user.